# Как вычислить каждое третье посещение сайта?

Tags: php

Как рассчитать все посещения на 1-й 2-й 3-й (как в армии)?
Чтобы каждую группу перенаправить на разные страницы.

Comment: Спасибо,помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если каждое третье с т.з. сайта, и не важно, один это посетитель, или разные, то, как и написал [@kovadim](/users/2739/kovadim), нужен счётчик хитов на стороне сервера, и редирект по результату остатка от деления на 3. При этом один и тот же чел. может увидеть то страницу-1, то страницу-2 или 3, зайдя в разное время.

Если же вы хотите именно аудиторию поделить на три потока, то можно маркировать посетителей куками, и редиректить в зависимости от значения куки:

```
define('ST_COOKIE_NAME', 'split_test', TRUE); // название куки
if( isset($_COOKIE[ST_COOKIE_NAME] ) {
    $group = $_COOKIE[ST_COOKIE_NAME];
} else { // куки нет, новый посетитель
    $group = rand(1,3);
    setcookie(ST_COOKIE_NAME, $group, 2592000, '/', 'mojsite.ru');
}
switch( $group) {
    case 1: $url = 'http://mojsite.ru/index1.html'; break;
    case 2: $url = 'http://mojsite.ru/index2.html'; break;
    case 3: default: $url = 'http://mojsite.ru/index3.html'; break;
}
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Comment: И Вам спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Найдите код любого примитивного счетчика посетителей (таких очень много). А дальше просто

```
$counter = getCounterValue(); # эта функция получила значение счетчика и обновила его
$p = ($counter % 3) + 1;
header("Location: http://www.example.com/index".$p.".html");
exit;
```

и приготовьте три страницы - index1.html, index2.html, index3.html.